# Check field validation in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have `UIAlertController` with input field. I want to check if this field is not empty and if field text is number. But i don't understand how to show validation message in alert window.

```
var inputTextField: UITextField?

        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter price", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continiue", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            let priceField = actionSheetController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            if let userPrice = priceField.text {
                if userPrice == "" {
                    //RETURN AND SHOW SHOW ERROR MESSAGE, BUT KEEP ALERT OPEN
                }
}
}
        actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)

        actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
            inputTextField = textField
            inputTextField!.placeholder = "Product price"
        }
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do validation? or how to show alert? Because the title of your questions is different from its body.

Comment: no, i mean how to display error when validation failed and don't close alert window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a string is a decimal number:

```
let nonDigits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
let isValidNumber : Bool = priceField.text?.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(nonDigits) == nil
```

Comment: i know how to check, i want to make this field required and don't close alert if it is not true

Comment: Why can't you use `UITextFieldKeyboardNumberPad` for `inputTextField`?

Comment: but how to check if it is empty ? The problem: when i click ok, my window will close in every case

Comment: Apple had `alertViewShouldEnableOtherButton:` delegate method in `UIAlertViewDelegate` but there is no shortcut to do this for `UIAlertController` 

Check out the workaround here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html